# javascript: get hex from long url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

For example i have such urls:

```
https://portalvhdsk7w6i7k9.blob.core.windows.net:443/project/5633cc12da73d9160c4cf146.dat
https://portalvhdsk7w6i7k9.blob.core.windows.com/project/5633cc12da73d9160c4cf146.dat
https://example.com/project/5633cc12da73d9160c4cf146.dat
```

can i somehow get only `5633cc12da73d9160c4cf146` using only js? is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string by `/` and the `pop()` the final element. Try this:

```
var url = 'https://portalvhdsk7w6i7k9.blob.core.windows.net:443/project/5633cc12da73d9160c4cf146.dat'
var hex = url.split('/').pop().replace('.dat', ''); // = '5633cc12da73d9160c4cf146'
```

If you want to get the location of the current page, use `document.location`.

Comment: No - it's replaced with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```js
var url = "https://portalvhdsk7w6i7k9.blob.core.windows.net:443/project/5633cc12da73d9160c4cf146.dat"

var indexofProd = url.indexOf("project/");
indexofProd = indexofProd + 8;

var indexofdotDat = url.indexOf(".dat");

var number = url.substring(indexofProd,indexofdotDat);

alert(number);
```